# Daily record, should each user have it's own table?

Tags: mysql

I have a check in system, and either users check in on a day, or they don't. How do I manage track of all the check ins? Should I create a table for each user and have a "present" and "date" columns, or is there a better way to manage this?

Comment: no you shouldn't have a table for each user... you should have one table that stores user data a table for logging when they checkin or not and another table linking the two or you could try to link the log table to the user table with a pk fk just would depend on what all you need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two tables, one table for user info & another table for check in info, create user id in first table & use this id in 2nd table, store info when any user checked in using this id, then you can easily track this information when you need.